# Is there more than one form of logic in mathematics?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

Is there more than one form of logic in mathematics? I would be inclined that mathematics only cover one type of formal logic, but I would be interested to know if there are variants thereof or completely different logics than what we're taught in university. In philosophy, there are several logics, but in mathematics it seems there's only one, or at least only one that's prevalent.

Comment: Hard to say what you mean by "form of logic", but there are parts of mathematics that are based on non-classical logics, [constructive mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_mathematics)#Constructive_mathematics) and [paraconsistent mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-inconsistent/) are the most prominent.

Comment: There is the syntactic and semantic.

Comment: Mathematics is not limited to any kind of logical system since it doesn't describe directly any phenomena. Scientist uses mathematical tools to interpret and describe the phenomena they're studying. In fact, with math, you can conceive any kind of logic! Richard Feynman described this nicely in his lectures on the [character of physical law.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3mhkYbznBk&list=PLez3PPtnpncQLg_H7f6T9yJmJ2aCIBUHS)

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: Please be aware that questions and answers are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Anything closed can be edited to bring it within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [MetaPhil](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Elliot That's not how it works.

Comment: Yes, on a fundamental level, much simple than fleshed out arithmetic, we have classical, non-classical, dialetheistic logic, just to name a few. We can build complex mathematical structures, like fields, etc, based on either one of those systems. So, yes, we most definitely have more than one form of logic in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on a fundamental level, much simpler than fleshed out arithmetic, we have classical, non-classical, dialetheistic logic, just to name a few.

You can choose either one of those systems and we can build complex mathematical structures, like fields, etc, using it - though it would be tedious, for example, if you don't have proof by contradiction at your disposal. So, yes, we most definitely have more than one form of logic in mathematics.